# Could a fat rocket be used on Mars?

Tags: mars, launch, rockets, physics

Since Mars' atmosphere is around 2% the density of Earth's then could a much wider rocket achieve orbit?

Could the rocket be in the shape of a capsule or an optimal shape for reentry on Earth?

[image]

Comment: With current activity on mars, this rocket has to somehow (one piece launch or built in orbit) reach low earth orbit first. Atmospheric density/drag/viscosity is one shape design consideration, gravity and ascent acceleration is an other one. Best shape for a rocket ignoring gravity and atmospheric drag could be something like a prolate spheroid with long axis aligned with thrust, or closer to one eggly shaped body of revolution.

Comment: @qqjkztd nice start to an answer.

Comment: Still waiting for the first textbook on Martian aerodynamics.

Comment: All Mars landers required a heat shield for entry to the marsian atmosphere. Parachutes were used for further slow down. So the influence of the atmosphere to a starting rocket can't be neglected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Here is a model of a two-stage, liquid-fueled Mars Ascent Vehicle that was designed to fit efficiently inside a squat aeroshell. Hence the squat shape.

[image: squat MAV]

It did have somewhat of a fairing on the front to mitigate drag. That was enough to get it to work in the trajectory simulations with only a small drag loss.

Comment: I was going to ask if this liquid-fueled Mars Ascent Vehicle have a name, then I read the sign in the foreground ;-) Still though, it would be fun to learn more, so I've just asked [How would this two-stage Mars Ascent Vehicle work? Where do you sit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35122/12102)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be possible.  Check out this [video of the launch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMYR-15EVOI) of a prototype for Zero2Infinity's balloon launched [Bloostar](http://www.zero2infinity.space/bloostar/) rocket.  It has 3 concentric stages resulting in a very squat look.

Bloostar is released at around 20-40 km altitude.  Surface atmospheric atmosphere on Mars is [equivalent to around 35km altitude on earth](http://planetary-science.org/mars-research/martian-atmosphere/).  So aerodynamically there is no gross reason why you couldn't do it, and it could potentially open up the avenue to different shaped payloads if they don't have to fit into a skinny fairing.

Carlos